# UNZIP error python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, unzip

i am trying to update a script from 2.7 to 3.5 i keep getting an error with the following.

def _openScure(self, new_image):
      return os.system("unzip "+new_image)

the issue is with unzip in python 3.5 what should i replace it with?

error says. 'unzip' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

i have tried the following.

import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile("name.zip", "r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref . extractall (".")
running win7 python 3.5 any ideas i would be most grateful.

So heres a link to the entire script i am trying to update to 3.5. The issue i am having is with line 17. Any thoughts?

https://github.com/agusmakmun/Some-Examples-of-Simple-Python-Script/blob/master/Stegano-Extract-and-Read-File-From-Image/script.py

Comment: `os.system` is just calling the external `unzip` command and it should work the same as in python 2. What error do you get?

Comment: tdelaney thanks for the reply error i am receiving is "unzip is not a reconsidered internal or external command". 
So it is looking for an external unzip command?

Comment: Yes. `os.system` just runs a command like you'd run from a terminal. Are you running on a different machine than the old python 2 stuff? See if you can run `unzip` from the command line. If it works,  try importing `os` and printing `os.environ['PATH']` and see if its the same as running `echo $PATH`. The problem isn't in the os.system call itself.

Comment: Thanks T that cleared up a lot for me. Will try it tonight and post on here if it works.